# How To Make A Print Helper for Qml in Cpp

Tags: qml, qprinter

I have created this class to print pdf files from qml,it is giving me error when executing, error appears after clicking some button ('my qml file is big so i did not share it'),any way problem is not from qml file,program executes and even first line of cpp code executes. error description and codes :

**my header file :**

```
#ifndef PRINTERHELPER_H
#define PRINTERHELPER_H

#include <QObject>

class PrinterHelper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PrinterHelper(QObject *parent = nullptr);

public:
Q_INVOKABLE void print(QString data);

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // PRINTERHELPER_H
```

**my cpp file :**

```
#include "printerhelper.h"
#include <QtPrintSupport/QPrinter>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QtPrintSupport/QPrintDialog>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QImage>
#include <qdebug.h>
PrinterHelper::PrinterHelper(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}
void  PrinterHelper::print(QString filename)
{
    qDebug()<<"Print file name is "<<filename;
    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
    printer.setOutputFileName(filename);
    QPrintDialog *dlg = new QPrintDialog(&printer,0);
    dlg->setWindowTitle(QObject::tr("Print Document"));

    if(dlg->exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
        QPainter painter;
        if (! painter.begin(&printer)) { // failed to open file
            qWarning("failed to open file, is it writable?");
            return;
        }
    }
    delete dlg;

}
```

**Qml Code :**

```
MouseArea{
       anchors.fill: parent
       onClicked: {                                  
           PRINT.print(file_directory+file_name)
       }
}
```

**error is :**

```
Print file name is  "C:/PishkhanTemp/saham_edalat/se_20190108150150.pdf"
QWidget: Cannot create a QWidget without QApplication
Debug Error!

Program: C:\QtN\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\msvc2017\bin\Qt5Cored.dll
Module: 5.12.0
File: kernel\qwidget.cpp
Line: 1126

QWidget: Cannot create a QWidget without QApplication
```

and i already changed to `#include <QApplication >`
**Update :**
error :
QPrintDialog: Cannot be used on non-native printers

Comment: It looks that Qt cannot find plugins folder or whatever. Can you provide the output of `QPrinterInfo::availablePrinters()`? Anyway see comments of [QTBUG-28822](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-28822?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true)

Comment: @folibis ("Microsoft XPS Document Writer") i have this in printers